# "PluginNotFoundException" when saving a view

Tags: views, 8, configuration

I download the backup of my front page view. Then I decide to remove it (using the UI) and then added back again using the configuration import. Then I try to edit that view and does not let me save the view.

When I try to save it show this error message...

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
>   "views.view.frontpage" plugin does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 57 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

#### Update

Here is my view import...

```
uuid: d0fec4c2-b8d0-4037-bf00-d8079069a6c3
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - core.entity_view_mode.node.rss
    - field.storage.node.body
    - field.storage.user.field_full_name
    - field.storage.user.user_picture
  module:
    - file
    - image
    - node
    - text
    - user
id: frontpage
label: Frontpage
module: node
description: 'All content promoted to the front page.'
tag: default
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      empty:
        area_text_custom:
          admin_label: ''
          content: 'No front page content has been created yet.'
          empty: true
          field: area_text_custom
          group_type: group
          id: area_text_custom
          label: ''
          relationship: none
          table: views
          tokenize: false
          plugin_id: text_custom
        node_listing_empty:
          admin_label: ''
          empty: true
          field: node_listing_empty
          group_type: group
          id: node_listing_empty
          label: ''
          relationship: none
          table: node
          plugin_id: node_listing_empty
          entity_type: node
        title:
          id: title
          table: views
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          empty: true
          title: 'Welcome to [site:name]'
          plugin_id: title
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      filters:
        promote:
          admin_label: ''
          expose:
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            label: ''
            multiple: false
            operator: ''
            operator_id: ''
            remember: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            required: false
            use_operator: false
          exposed: false
          field: promote
          group: 1
          group_info:
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            description: ''
            group_items: {  }
            identifier: ''
            label: ''
            multiple: false
            optional: true
            remember: false
            widget: select
          group_type: group
          id: promote
          is_grouped: false
          operator: '='
          relationship: none
          table: node_field_data
          value: true
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: promote
        status:
          expose:
            operator: ''
          field: status
          group: 1
          id: status
          table: node_field_data
          value: true
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
        langcode:
          id: langcode
          table: node_field_data
          field: langcode
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value:
            '***LANGUAGE_language_content***': '***LANGUAGE_language_content***'
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: language
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: langcode
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 10
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: 0
          tags:
            previous: '‹ Previous'
            next: 'Next ›'
            first: '« First'
            last: 'Last »'
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          quantity: 9
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      row:
        type: fields
        options:
          default_field_elements: false
          inline: {  }
          separator: ''
          hide_empty: false
      sorts:
        sticky:
          admin_label: ''
          expose:
            label: ''
          exposed: false
          field: sticky
          group_type: group
          id: sticky
          order: DESC
          relationship: none
          table: node_field_data
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: sticky
        created:
          field: created
          id: created
          order: DESC
          table: node_field_data
          plugin_id: date
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: false
      title: ''
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      relationships:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: node_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: author
          required: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: standard
        user_picture_target_id:
          id: user_picture_target_id
          table: user__user_picture
          field: user_picture_target_id
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: 'image from user_picture'
          required: false
          plugin_id: standard
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: false
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
        body:
          id: body
          table: node__body
          field: body
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: false
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: text_trimmed
          settings:
            trim_length: 148
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
        user_picture:
          id: user_picture
          table: user__user_picture
          field: user_picture
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: '<p> <br>'
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: author-thumb
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: false
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: image
          settings:
            image_style: medium
            image_link: ''
          group_column: ''
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
        field_full_name:
          id: field_full_name
          table: user__field_full_name
          field: field_full_name
          relationship: uid
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: false
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: false
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: custom
            custom_date_format: 'j  F  Y'
            timezone: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: field
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    display_plugin: default
    display_title: Master
    id: default
    position: 0
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: -1
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.field_full_name'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.user_picture'
  feed_1:
    display_plugin: feed
    id: feed_1
    display_title: Feed
    position: 2
    display_options:
      sitename_title: true
      path: rss.xml
      displays:
        page_1: page_1
        default: ''
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          items_per_page: 10
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: rss
        options:
          description: ''
          grouping: {  }
          uses_fields: false
      row:
        type: node_rss
        options:
          relationship: none
          view_mode: rss
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: -1
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.field_full_name'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.user_picture'
  page_1:
    display_options:
      path: node
      display_extenders: {  }
    display_plugin: page
    display_title: Page
    id: page_1
    position: 1
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: -1
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.field_full_name'
        - 'config:field.storage.user.user_picture'
```

My question is how I can fix my view so I can keep saving my new views changes?

Comment: views.view.frontpage is a config, not a plugin, so this error makes no sense. I think you might have imported the config as something else(if it is even possible) and not a view?

Comment: I'm sure that I upload the correct view. I will try it out to do again.... to see what happen.

Comment: I was able to reupload the same view and I still have the same error. However, if I rename the view to something else that is not "frontpage" is going to work fine.

Comment: Which makes me wonder - is there any other config out there containing the term "frontpage". Maybe some other config is already there that is interacting with your imported config when it is called "frontpage".